# How to get the page model along with grid transactions (iggrid) to server in ASP.NETMVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, infragistics, iggrid

I am working on ASP.NETMVC and iggrid (Infragistics). Is there any way I can pass the page  model along with  grid transactions  to server (controller from view)?

Thanks in advance.